# Not one-to-one functions of $m$ element sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Is the total number of noninjective or not one-to-one functions for two sets of the same size $m$, equal to $m^m - m!$?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, number of functions from a set of size $m$ to another set of size $m$ is $m^m$ as each element in the domain ($m$ of them ) have $m$ options to choose from. Hence $m^m$ functions.

The number of injective function would be $m!$ as we can sort the member of the domain. The first element has $m$ choices, the second element has $m-1$ choices, $\ldots$the $i$-th element has $m-(i-1)$ options to avoid repeating the choices made earlier. Hence there are $m!$ injective functions.

Hence there are $m^m-m!$ non-injective functions.

Comment: Got it! thanks a lot @Siong Thye Goh